# Spectrum of eigen values for coupled differential equations

Tags: difference-equations, eigenvalues

How do I obtain a spectrum of eigenvalues for my system of coupled differential equations?

$$
kf''(\theta) + \epsilon_{1} f(\theta) + a\cos(b \theta + c) g(\theta) = \lambda f(\theta),\\
a\cos(b \theta + c) f(\theta) + k g''(\theta) + \epsilon_{2}g(\theta) = \lambda g(\theta)
$$

The system has periodic boundary conditions:

$$
f(\theta +2\pi) = f(\theta)\\
g(\theta +2\pi) = g(\theta)
$$

I have tried using `NDEigensystem`, but I would like to plot a spectrum of the eigen values with varying parameters $ \left[ k, \epsilon_{1},\epsilon_{2},a,b,c \right] $.
Here is a bit of code that I tried, but it doesn't work the way I want.

```
eqns= {k f''[\[Theta]] + Subscript[\[Epsilon], 1 ] f[\[Theta]] + a Cos[b \[Theta] + c] g[\[Theta]],
k g''[\[Theta]] + Subscript[\[Epsilon], 2 ] g[\[Theta]] + a Cos[b \[Theta] + c] f[\[Theta]] }
bc =  PeriodicBoundaryCondition[g[\[Theta]], \[Theta] == 2 \[Pi],Function[\[Theta], \[Theta] - 2 \[Pi]]]
{vals,funs}= NDEigensystem[{eqns,bc}/.{k->1,Subscript[\[Epsilon], 1 ]->1,Subscript[\[Epsilon], 2 ]->1,a->1,b->1,c->1},{f[\[Theta]], g[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 0, 2\[Pi]}, 50]
```

I am looking for a way to vary the variable I previously mentioned and see how they change using a function similar to `Manipulate`.

Comment: Would be a good idea to give some Mathematica code for the equations.

Comment: @VijayMocherla Can you add a minimal working code example of what you tried in your question? This makes it much easier for people to see what you were trying to do and give you a helpful answer.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke Thanks for the suggestion. I have just added that to my original question.

Answer (score 3):

How about this as a start:

```
Manipulate[
 {vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{eqns, bc} /. {k -> kk, 
     Subscript[\[Epsilon], 1] -> ee1, Subscript[\[Epsilon], 2] -> ee2,
      a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1}, {f[\[Theta]], g[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 
    0, 2 \[Pi]}, 5];
 Plot[funs, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
 , {kk, 1/2, 2}
 , {ee1, 1/2, 2}
 , {ee2, 1/2, 2}
 ]
```